# A bit of a Jquery UI Scale+ CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a small slider where jquery UI Scale brings out and image Div and scales out the first one. My problem is, when it gets scaled in Google Chrome it shakes a bit while its in the process of scaling. In IE or firefox it works like a charm no vibrating/shaking at all!

Now I tested that when I don't use background-position:center in css it doesn't shake anymore but If i take this out then it doesn't look like its being zoomed out from the center of the image anymore. 
What can I do to get rid of this?
Here is an example(Open it with Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/gqLZe/

Comment: This sounds like either a google chrome or jQuery bug.

Comment: My guess is it's due to rounding errors in calculating the center of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the animation in slow motion (very long duration), I can see that the bottom of the div actually moves up a pixel occasionally - which is what is causing the shaking.  Watching it in the style inspector, I can see that jQuery is setting each of the position properties of the div to a decimal, and the position of the div actually changes each time one of those decimals passes a whole number.  Since the top and height don't necessarily pass a whole number at that same time, you get the shaking.  On the other hand, the left and width do appear to always pass a whole number at the same time, though I can't tell for sure whether that's the case.  In any case, I haven't been able to distinguish any horizontal shaking.

Apparently Chrome is truncating any decimals in the position properties, whereas the other browsers are using floating-point arithmetic to calculate the boundary of the div in absolute coordinates before any rounding or truncating.  I'm not sure whether this qualifies as a bug or not (would have to examine the spec), though it's likely something that will get fixed/improved eventually.  It probably does qualify as a bug in jQuery, since jQuery is supposed to work around such browser peculiarities.

Fixing this problem requires providing a different scaling algorithm.  One solution is to compute in JavaScript the values that the other browsers are computing automatically, and provide only whole numbers to Chrome, as in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqLZe/1/

That method may cause a similar problem in other browsers when a containing element has a noninteger top or left (including due to border or margin), but so long as you stick to whole numbers, it should work fine.

An alternate solution would be to provide a parent element of the size that you want the div to expand to, and animate on `right` and `bottom` rather than on `width` and `height`.  This can be done very simply using jQuery's `animate()`:

```
var width = $(".frame").width();
var height = $(".frame").height();
$(".frame").css({
    top: height / 2 + "px",
    bottom: height / 2 + "px",
    left: width / 2 + "px",
    right: width / 2 + "px"
}).show().animate({
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
}, 3000, 'linear');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqLZe/3/

That's probably the way to go, if you can endure having an extra markup element.